# How do I get a count of associated rows in a left join in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join, subquery

I have two tables, a `vehicle` table with columns:

- `id`
- `stock`
- `year`
- `make`
- `model`

and an `images` table with columns:

- `id`
- `vehicle_id`
- `name`
- `caption`
- `default tinyint(1)`

I am trying to list the vehicle's information, its default image, and a total count of images the vehicle has.  Currently I am using the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT vehicle.id, vehicle.stock, vehicle.year,
    vehicle.make, vehicle.model, images.name,
    COUNT(images.id)
FROM vehicle
LEFT JOIN images
ON vehicle.id = images.vehicle_id
```

I initially was using:

```
ON vehicle.id = images.vehicle_id AND images.default = 1
```

but then the images count would only be 1 or 0 depending if there was a default image in the database.  I have tried using `UNION` and other `SELECT` statements but I am still unable to get a proper result.  Do I need to use two `SELECT` statements or is there another way to handle it with `JOIN` or `UNION`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    `vehicle`.`id`, 
    `vehicle`.`stock`, 
    `vehicle`.`year`, 
    `vehicle`.`make`, 
    `vehicle`.`model`, 
    `images`.`name`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `images` 
        WHERE `vehicle_id` = `vehicle`.`id`
    ) AS `image_count`
FROM `vehicle`
LEFT JOIN `images`
ON `images`.`vehicle_id` = `vehicle`.`id`
WHERE `images`.`default`
```

Comment: I agree. This would be the correct way to do this. I can think of another way (involving using a subquery instead of the straight images table) but it is hacky and hideous (and just for fun). This is the right way to do this.

Comment: +1 for this. I cleaned it up just a little for getting rid of the scroll

Comment: Is it better to use COUNT(id) instead of COUNT(*) so that I am not selecting all of the columns?

Comment: Makes no difference in this situation.  In general, COUNT(*) should be used when what you mean is "how many rows".  COUNT(id) means "how many ids that aren't null", which may or may not be a much more involved question.

Comment: if mysql supported CTE's i's post that solution

Comment: I believe there are some performance benefits for using `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(id)` when querying MyISAM tables, since I believe they store the total row count. However, this can probably only be used if you do not have any conditions in your query.

Answer (score 7):

In the way the anser suggests, you get repeated values of "vehicle". A better way, is to group results. Try without the JOIN :

```
SELECT 
    `vehicle`.`id`, 
    `vehicle`.`stock`, 
    `vehicle`.`year`, 
    `vehicle`.`make`, 
    `vehicle`.`model`, 
    `images`.`name`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `images` 
        WHERE `vehicle_id` = `vehicle`.`id`
    ) AS `image_count`
FROM `vehicle`

WHERE `images`.`default`
```

Comment: This one is better than accepted answer, @giuseppe try to edit accepted answer, maybe author will change it

Answer (score 5):

## Let me make it clear for everyone!

**Task**: Print 3 columns table:

1. Vehicles (titles) from **vehicles** table.
2. Amount of comments for each vehicle from **comments** table.
3. Amount of images for each vehicle from **images** table.

**Expected output (just an example)**:

```
+----------------------+----------------+--------------+
|        title         | comments_count | images_count |
+----------------------+----------------+--------------+
| BMW X6               |             35 |            9 |
| Audi A6              |              3 |            5 |
| Volkswagen Passat B6 |             78 |            6 |
| Volkswagen Passat B5 |            129 |            4 |
+----------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

**Solution**:

```
SELECT 
    vehicles.title,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE vehicles.id = comments.vehicle_id) AS comments_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE vehicles.id = images.vehicle_id) AS images_count
FROM vehicles
```