# Which join for 1: Many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Here is my Database schema and the tables I am trying to link, I tried using a **LEFT** join but now it is creating a new result for each matched row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qItTW.png

I am currently building up my query and now trying to join these tables together **(Procedure-> Procedure_event -> Resources -> Med_item)**

In a scenario like this:

> e.g. Procedure X has 3 rows procedure_events

I want the data returned to me in one record but with all the rows that make up that record.

However it is returning 3 rows of results like so:

- Procedure X - procedure_event row 1
- Procedure X - procedure_event row 2
- Procedure X - procedure_event row 3

So the query result should be **Procedure X - procedureevent rows 1,2,3**

This is my code in Codeigniter PHP framework using Active Record:

```
$this->db->join('procedure_event', 'procedure.procedure_id = procedure_event.procedure_id' , 'left');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how LEFT JOIN works.

> So the query result should be Procedure X - procedureevent rows 1,2,3

I think you need this: [How do I get a count of associated rows in a left join in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808475/how-do-i-get-a-count-of-associated-rows-in-a-left-join-in-mysql)

MySQL can't return two dimensional arrays, or merge rows. If you need all the "procedureevent rows 1,2,3" then just iterate through the result set, like you would normally do and add a small + icon that gets the procedureevents with AJAX.

Comment: I think what I will do is two seperate queries and merge their results into one array